# Как корректно организовать component для просмотра item из списка items на Angular 2?

Tags: angular2, typescript, crud

Есть сервис, который получает массив `items` через `http` запрос, `url` вида `/items`, либо один `item` - соответственно, `url` вида `/items/<id>`. Вывожу `items` на страницу через `component` `Items` путем перебора в цикле `*ngFor`, но как лучше сделать просмотр подробной информации об `item` - визуально на новой странице с перезагрузкой страницы или без перезагрузки.

Предположим, в списке `items` делаю для каждого `item` ссылку перехода на страницу просмотра, ссылка вида `/items/<id>`, посредством маршрутизации переадресую обработку компоненту `ItemsId`, который использует общий для `Items` и `ItemsId` сервис `ItemsService`

А как получить тот самый `id` и передать его в нужное место внутри класса в компоненте для последующего вызова метода сервиса? Если я правильно понимаю, в любом случае необходимо завести некое поле `id` для хранения этого идентификатора, но в какой момент его заполнять?

**Update:**
Маршрутизатор переадресует обработку `url` вида `/items/21` на нужный компонент `ItemsIdComponent`, однако значение `id=21` пока не удалось получить в классе `ItemsIdComponent`.

*app.routes.ts*

```
import { ItemsIdComponent } from "./components/items/items-id.component";
...
export const routes: Routes =[
 ...
  { path: 'items/:id', component: ItemsIdComponent},
 ...
];
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';    
...
import { ItemsIdComponent } from './components/items/items-id.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routes';
import { ItemsService } from "./components/items/items.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
   ItemsIdComponent
 ],
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    ...
    ItemsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*items-id.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
//import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ItemsService } from "./items.service";
import { Item } from "./items";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "items-id",
  templateUrl: "items-id.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["items-id.component.scss"]
})
export class ItemsIdComponent implements OnInit {
  item: Item;
  id:number;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor( private service: ItemsService,
              /* private router: Router, */ 
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.id = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['id'];    
 console.log('id='+this.id+'route='+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['id']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private getItem(id) {
    this.service.getItem(id).then(
      item=> this.item = item,
      error => this.errorMessage = error
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Я опечатался в ответе, вместо `queryParams` надо `params`. Посмотрите обновленный ответ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо большое, получилось. А объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница между `queryParams` и `params`? queryParams это случайно не для передачи параметров вроде `/items?id=21&name=qwerty` ?

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы  `queryParams` это для передачи параметров вроде `/items?id=21&name=qwerty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить параметр из `url` можно с помощью `ActivatedRoute`.

```
import {Component,  OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router"; // делаем импорт

@Component({
selector: 'app-sound-maker',
templateUrl: './sound-maker.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sound-maker.component.scss'],
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  public id:number;// поле для сохранения id
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { // инициализируем экземпляр класса ActivatedRoute
     //Получаем id из url. 
     //Url вида ...item/21, где 21 - это id. 
     //В роутинге должно быть прописано так item/:id         
     this.id = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']; 

  }
}
```

Comment: роутинг срабатывает на `items/:id`, переходит при ссылке вида `/items/21` к нужному компоненту, однако `id` таким образом не получает, значение `Nan`

Comment: `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['id']` - `undefined`

Comment: @Emm Обновляйте вопрос, показывайте код, что и как сделали)